# RESTful URLs with Django

Tags: django, restful-url

I've been trying out Ruby on Rails and really like the RESTful approach for the URL's.
Now I'm trying to learn Django and I want to create the same kind of nested URL's as I did with Rails.

Lets say I wanna do this: `/categories/12/products/13`

This is what I've came up with, but does not seem to work:

```
url(r'^categories/(?P<category_id>\d+)/products/(?P<product_id>\d+/$)', 'my_app.views.product', name="product"),
```

How should this be done? Also, how could you use the `url` template helper for creating this kind of link?

Comment: Not being familiar with RoR, I'm not sure what you're asking, but does https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs do what you're looking for?

Comment: You're right. I made a typo in the regex. <product_id>\d+/$) should be <product_id>\d+)/$. It works.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [TastyPie](http://tastypieapi.org/). It's a drop-in REST Api for Django similar to what you're used to in Rails and will get you going in the right direction without too much work.

Comment: OK thanks I will check it out. So the "normal" way of doing Django URL's is not to nest them I presume?

Comment: No, there's no concept of resources in Django. URLs are specified in order of the most specific pattern to the least specific. However, it's possible to include patterns from one app's URL's in another. This allows you to keep URL patterns pretty DRY.

Comment: I did however manage to nest the URL now... I just made a little regex typo. <product_id>\d+/$) should be <product_id>\d+)/$

Answer (score 1):

Glad you got it sorted, as TastyPie was mentioned I would also recommend [Django REST framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) also.

Answer (score 0):

In a template you can use `<a href="{% url product category_id product_id %}">Link title</a>`

To create a url in your python code you can use `reverse`:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

url = reverse('product', args=[category_id, product_id])
```